# Is there a Java code to convert csv files into pbix?

Tags: java, csv, type-conversion, powerbi

We need a Java code which automatically converts csv files into pbix files, so they can be opened and further worked on in the PowerBI Desktop. Now, I know PowerBI offers this super cool feature, which converts csv files and many other formats into pbix manually. However, we need a function which automatically converts our reports directly into pbix, so that no intermediate files need to be created and stored somewhere.

We have already been able to develop a function with three parameters: The first one corresponds to the selected report, from our database; the second corresponds to the directory, in which the converted report should be generated; and finally the third one is the converted output file itself. The two first parameters work well and the code is able to generate a copy of any report we select into any directory we select. However, it is able to generate csv files only. Any other format will have the same size as the csv and won't be able to open.

This is what we've tried so far for the conversion part of the code:

```
      Util.writeFile("C:\\" + "test.csv",  byteString);
```

The above piece of code works just fine, however csv is not what we wanted, the original reports are already in csv format anyway.

```
      Util.writeFile("C:\\" + "test.pbix",  byteString);
      Util.writeFile("C:\\" + "test.pdf",  byteString);  
      Util.writeFile("C:\\" + "test.xlsx",  byteString);
```

Each of the three lines above generates one file in the indicated format, however each of the generated files are just as large as its corresponding csv(but should be much larger) and therefore are unable to open.

```
      File file = new File("C:\\" + "test1.csv");
      File file2 = new File("C:\\" + "test1.pbix");
      file.renameTo(file2);
```

The above piece of code does not generate any file at all, but I thought it could be worth mentioning it, as it doesn't throw any exception at all either.

P.S. We would also be interested in a java code which converts csv in any other BI reporting software besides PowerBI, like Tableau, BIRT, Knowage, etc.

P.S.2 The first piece of code uses objects of a class (sailpoint.tools.Util) which is apparently only available for those who have access to Sailpoint.

Comment: A lot easier said than done. To see what is actually contained within a **.pbix** file, change the **.pbix** file name extension to **.zip** then decompress the file with WinRAR or 7Zip.  You want to convert a CSV data file to that? Better to just convert the CSV to a XML type format file since in reality, that's partly what a pbix file is (a series of compressed XML files).

Comment: Hello, DevilsHnd, and thank you very much for your answer.
It is definitely possible to convert csv to xml. However, I've never converted one single file into several files. Do you think that this is possible? How could that be done?
Or do you mean to convert the csv into one single xml, which describes all the series of compressed xml files that make up the one pbix? Would this work?